# jquery find next / prev in tree

Tags: javascript, jquery

given a structure like:

```
<div class="tree">
   <div class="item" />
   <div class="item" />
   <div class="item" />
   <div class="item" />
   <div class="group">
      <div class="item" />
      <div class="item" />
      <div class="item" />
   </div>
   <div class="item" />
   <div class="group">
      <div class="item" />
      <div class="item selected" />
      <div class="item" />
      <div class="item" />
   </div>
   <div class="group">
      <div class="item" />
      <div class="item" />
   </div>
</div>
```

I would like to be able to go to the next and previous item in the three. 
I have the following js

```
//to go up
var currentSelected = $(".item.selected");
currentSelected.removeClass("selected");
currentSelected.prevAll(".item:first").addClass("selected");

//to go down
var currentSelected = $(".item.selected");
currentSelected.removeClass("selected");
currentSelected.nextAll(".item:first").addClass("selected");
```

However, this does not work accros the groups, if I go up and am currently at the first item of a group, I would like to select either the item before the group, or the last item of the group before the current group. And vice versa for go down.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

It would be best if you find the next/prev item from a jQuery collection:

```
var $items = $('.item');
```

You should then loop over them to find the current selected index and move to the item you are looking for based on it:

```
$items.each(function(index) {
    var $item = $(this);

    if ($item.hasClass('selected')) {
       $item.removeClass('selected');

       var $nextItem = $items.eq(index + 1); // to select the next one

       $nextItem.addClass('selected');
    }
});
```